# Docker file mount understanding

Tags: docker

I'am using docker and I have a strange behaviour when I try to mount a container file on a host file.

```
docker run -v /var/tmp/foo.txt:/var/tmp/foo.txt myapp
```

The command above runs myapp container which creates a foo.txt file into the /var/tmp directory into the container. Because I need to keep this file on host after myapp dies, I create a mounting point.

My problem is that instead of creating foo.txt as a file on host, I end up with an empty directory named "foo.txt" (and nothing inside).

But, if I create an empty text file foo.txt on host and  if I run myapp again, it works as expected.

So, my question is, Do I need to create the file on host before starting the container when I use file mount with docker?

I think I missed something. Thank you for your explanations.

Comment: Create a folder mount, like `docker run -v $(pwd):/var/tmp myapp`. Then when you create foo.txt in `/var/tmp` in the container, it will be persisted in the working directory on your host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact as you discovered, to mount a host file as a data volume the file must exists otherwise docker will create a directory and mount it.

From: https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/

## Mount a host file as a data volume

The `-v` flag can also be used to mount a single file - instead of *just* directories - from the host machine.

```
$ docker run --rm -it -v ~/.bash_history:/root/.bash_history ubuntu /bin/bash
```

Note it never says that the file doesn't exists on host.

As suggested in the comment it is better to mount a directory if you want the container writes into it.

Regards